# Not matched, checked lots of times

Tags: sql, oracle

Googled quite a lot for the errors but I just can't seems to find the solution. 
These are my codes

```
create table valuation (   
    propertyNum VARCHAR2(255), 
    dateInspected DATE, 
    rent VARCHAR2(255),
    deposit VARCHAR2(255),
    PRIMARY KEY (propertyNum, dateInspected),
    FOREIGN KEY (propertyNum) REFERENCES property,
    FOREIGN KEY (dateInspected) REFERENCES inspection
);
```

---

```
create table inspection (   
    propertyNum VARCHAR2(255), 
    dateInspected DATE, 
    staffNum VARCHAR2(255),
    comments CHAR(255), 
    PRIMARY KEY (propertyNum, dateInspected),
    FOREIGN KEY (propertyNum) REFERENCES property,
    FOREIGN KEY (staffNum) REFERENCES staff
);
```

The error seems to be at this part:

```
FOREIGN KEY (dateInspected) REFERENCES inspection);
```

because I've tried removing this part and it works fine.

Error Message:

> ORA-02256: number of referencing columns must match referenced columns

Comment: @GordonLinoff Maybe use my edit, as I formatted the entire portion of SQL statements

Comment: @Xayn . . . The table referred to by the foreign key has to be defined before the foreign key reference.

Comment: @GordonLinoff thanks for the quick assist. Tried both, still the same. Error only appears when i'm doing valuation part. Inspection works just fine

Comment: What's the error message?

Comment: @SSteven sorry, I've added it in now. It's the ORA-02256

Comment: do the other table PKs have the same column name as your fk column?  if not you might have to explicity call it out e.g. foreign key (propertyNum, dateInspected) references inspection (propertyId, dateOfInspection)

Answer (score 0):

This does not work, because the foreign key, which you are trying to define from the "valuation" table is based on just one column ("dateInspected"), while the primary key of the parent/master table ("inspection") does not have a one-column primary (or unique) key. It has a two-column one (on "propertyNum" and "dateInspected" columns)

The requirement for creating a foreign key is for the master/parent table having a matching primary key or a matching unique constraint.

What you might have wanted is this:

```
FOREIGN KEY (propertyNum, dateInspected) REFERENCES inspection
```

Answer (score 0):

As Hilarion points out, the error you're receiving is due to multipart Primary key and single part foreign keys.  But try some additional changes that will make the references easier and clean up your relation model.

Add an Identity column to both Valuation and Inspection and try these schema changes.

```
valuation (  
id, 
propertyNum, 
inspectionId, 
rent,
deposit,
PRIMARY KEY (id),
FOREIGN KEY (propertyNum) REFERENCES property,
FOREIGN KEY (inspectionId) REFERENCES inspection )

inspection (   
id,
propertyNum, 
dateInspected, 
staffNum,
comments, 
PRIMARY KEY (id),
FOREIGN KEY (propertyNum) REFERENCES property,
FOREIGN KEY (staffNum) REFERENCES staff )
```

You'll need to plug in your datatypes (I recommend using a numeric field for your rent and deposit instead of varchar)

Also replace the dateInspected field on the property table with lastDateInspected.

I would do this because logically a property could be inspected and valuated more than once.  Also, it will clean up your relationships.  You'll be able to pull a history of inspections and valuations without changing other property data.

Notice, that your valuations can be linked to an inspection, but an inspection doesn't care at all about a valuation, it doesn't and shouldn't need to.